# Creating masks across browsers

Tags: javascript, css, image, mask

I see that there are ways to do this in webkit browsers, but I don't see ways to do it in others. Is this simply a feature that hasn't been implemented in all the browsers?

I don't have standard images, so clip won't work. I may have to render everything ahead of time, which will make my work exponential, but you deal with what you have, right?

I'd also want to be able to activate this stuff from javascript. :/

Thanks if you can provide support.

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific as to what you want done. What **specific problem** do you need to solve? Some HTML and CSS would be nice to have...

Comment: A mask is a black & white image that overlays another image to make parts of it invisible and other parts of it visible. I just needed to know if there was a way to do this in browsers, but apparently not. I guess I'm looking at doing it in an SWF if I want it to be cross browser compatible from the get go, but that's not really ideal  in anyway at all. There's either a way to do masks or there isn't. I shouldn't need to provide code.

Comment: Well, if you want to simply "mask out" parts of an image, search for "CSS Sprite". That's why I wanted to know whether or not u could supply code. And this could also be easily changed on the fly using javascript. So, if this is what you're after, I can supply a solution.

Comment: CSS Sprite might do the trick. I'm looking into it a little more. I have about 10 images that need to be stacked one on top of another and masked out depending on the settings to reflect user choices. They all fit together. The masks are currently black and white. Sometimes the masks are needed and sometimes they aren't. So I want to be able to adjust whether an image exists and what its mask is on the fly.

Comment: I've added my preferred solution to this problem (CSS Sprites) below. Try it out and let me know if this solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to skip the CSS variant in favor of this:

Example of a working mask: http://gumonshoe.net/NewCard/MaskTest.html

I acquired a javascript class from another website tutorial:
http://gumonshoe.net/js/canvasMask.js

It reads the image data and applies the alpha pixels from the mask to the target image:

```
function applyCanvasMask(image, mask, width, height, asBase64) {
    // check we have Canvas, and return the unmasked image if not
    if (!document.createElement('canvas').getContext) return image;

    var bufferCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        buffer = bufferCanvas.getContext('2d'),
        outputCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        output = outputCanvas.getContext('2d'),

        contents = null,
        imageData = null,
        alphaData = null;

    // set sizes to ensure all pixels are drawn to Canvas
    bufferCanvas.width = width;
    bufferCanvas.height = height * 2;
    outputCanvas.width = width;
    outputCanvas.height = height;

    // draw the base image
    buffer.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    // draw the mask directly below
    buffer.drawImage(mask, 0, height);

    // grab the pixel data for base image
    contents = buffer.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

    // store pixel data array seperately so we can manipulate
    imageData = contents.data;

    // store mask data
    alphaData = buffer.getImageData(0, height, width, height).data;

    // loop through alpha mask and apply alpha values to base image
    for (var i = 3, len = imageData.length; i < len; i = i + 4) {
        imageData[i] = alphaData[i];
    }

    // return the pixel data with alpha values applied
    if (asBase64) {
        output.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        output.putImageData(contents, 0, 0);

        return outputCanvas.toDataURL();
    }
    else {
        return contents;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just off the top of my head - and **without an actual problem** from you for us to solve - here's a possible way to accomplish what you want...

**HTML**

```
<div class="myImage">

    <img src="path_to_image" title="Lorem ipsum" alt="Dolar sit amet" />    

    <div class="myMask">
    </div><!-- /myMask -->

</div><!-- /myImage -->
```

**CSS**

```
.myImage {
    position: relative;
}

.myMask {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url('path_to_masking_image');
}
```

*Alternatively, use an `<img />` inside the `myMask` div, and remove the  `background-image` property from the CSS.*

---

The way it's currently laid out, you would need two images: the image itself in all its glory, and the mask.

The way you would accomplish the 'masking effect' is to have the mask image be a static solid color that matches background of the container its in - ie white, black, whatever.

Kapeesh? This would work in all browsers, which is what you asked for. The `background-clip` property has -webkit and -moz selectors, but is not supported in browsers like IE or (to my knowledge) Opera.

Comment: If I wasn't working with putting multiple images on top of each other that might work, but the idea is that behind the masked image there isn't one solid color. Which is why masks are generally great.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my 2 cents, if it is indeed CSS Sprites you are after.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css"><!--
#imagemask {
    background-image: url(image.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
.mask1 { background-position: top left; }
.mask2 { background-position: 0 40px; }
.mask3 { background-position: 0 80px; }/* And so on, however your image file is 'layed out' */
--></style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mask1(){ document.getElementById("imagemask").setAttribute("class", "mask1"); }
    function mask2(){ document.getElementById("imagemask").setAttribute("class", "mask1"); }
    function mask3(){ document.getElementById("imagemask").setAttribute("class", "mask1"); }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:mask1()">mask 1</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:mask2()">mask 2</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:mask3()">mask 3</a>
    <div id="imagemask" class="mask1"></div>
</body>
```

1. We define the div#imagemask to contain 1 image file as a background and set it to not repeat around, as that would sort of defy the point.
2. We define how to "move around" the image inside the "mask" (div) with fixed width and height.
3. As a reference, I've then added the javascript you need to switch between the masks on the fly. I wrote that in about 10 seconds, you could probably write something a little more elegant if you want.
4. Add the links with onclick= events
5. Finally, add the div#imagemask to the body.

Given that I don't know the width or height of your image file or it's target masking, you'll have to do some substantial edits to this code. But you get the idea :)

Comment: Definately a way to do what I need, but I've found a more elegant way to do it as described above that completely meets my needs without exploding images into various components. Unfortunately, it needs <canvas> but that's fine by me. I'll detail the solution I'm actually going to go with somewhere on this page once I have it nailed down and have solution for people to read.